# Do formal language theory have concepts corresponding to dependency grammars?

Tags: dependency-grammar

If I am correct, [phrase structure grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar) in linguistics are the grammars for recursively enumerable languages.

Do formal language theory have concepts corresponding to [dependency grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar), the concept in contrast to phrase structure grammars in linguistics?

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely yes. Broadly speaking, abstract syntax trees are dependency trees, a simple context-free grammar for arithmetic expressions reveals this fact clearly. I’d recommend looking at attribute grammars invented by Donald Knuth (the article on Wikipedia has links to Knuth’s papers). Rule-based dependency parsers work like attribute grammars, they recognise constituents and incrementally build up the dependency tree (or dag).

Comment: [Control flow graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph) and similar things might come close, but they are concerned with sequences of statements, not single expression, and don't have such a nice relationship to parse trees.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is called **abstract syntax tree (AST)** in the theory of formal languages. Consider a simple grammar for arithmetic expressions and the following input string: `2/(3-4)`. It has the following **concrete syntax tree (CST)**:

[image]

The corresponding abstract syntax tree is somewhat simpler:

[image]

Note that the nodes of the AST are the leaves of the CST so an AST is to CST as a dependency tree is to a phrase structure tree. There are more analogies — note that some leaves present in the CST are missing from the AST (the brackets) because they’re ancillary — they aid the parsing process but don’t contribute to the meaning of the expression. There are some more analogies such as complex predicates but that’s more involved.

Knuth’s attribute grammars are the mechanism for parsing that builds up both trees in step.

Comment: The analogy is interesting, but I do not think it matches the dependency vs. phrase structure distinction fully. I can see that automatic conversion from the CST to the AST is likely possible, but going in the opposite direction may be more difficult. In particular, how would one translate the AST to a CST that allows strictly binary branching structures only?

Comment: @TimOsborne Binarily branching CSTs wouldn’t make any sense. The relationship is clearly many-to-one. It’s also obvious that ASTs contain less information than CSTs but there’s an algorithm (invented by Ron Kaplan) that takes an AST and produces the corresponding CST(s). In linguistics it can be used for generation.

Comment: OK, so I guess that helps establish my point. Much of modern phrase structure syntax assumes strict binarity of branching, yet the CSTs you point to are not like that. I of course agree that dependency analyses can be converted to phrase structure analyses, and vice versa, but what cannot be done (at least not in a straightforward way) is conversion from dependency structures to those phrase structures in which all branching is strictly binary.

Comment: @TimOsborne I don’t think that’s correct, it’s a well-known theorem that any phrase structure grammar is equivalent to a grammar with solely binary rules so a conversion algorithm wouldn’t care about binary branching at all.

Comment: What if the phrase structures are exocentric? How is the conversion going to work in that case?

Comment: @TimOsborne Exocentricity is irrelevant for the algorithm, it’s universal. Have you read the paper by Kaplan?

Comment: No, I haven't read the paper by Kaplan. There must, however, be some sort of misconception going on here, since my understanding of of exocentric structures (i.e. headless structures) is that they are incompatible with dependency. Perhaps your understanding of exocentric structures is distinct from mine.

Comment: @TimOsborne I think there’s only one definition of exocentricity, this concept isn’t controversial. The algorithm is nice and straightforward. Every phrase has at least one functional head, regardless of endocentricity, it doesn’t use this notion at all. It constitutes a constructive proof that dependency trees can be automatically converted into phrase structure trees, including purely binary trees.

Comment: I couldn't see a link to the Kaplan paper you mention (I did google, obvs). The discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410302/converting-a-parse-tree-to-ast reads as though a CST cannot be mapped to an AST without some degree of arbitrariness, whereas it sounds like that's exactly what Kaplan's algorithm does. I think you are saying above that an algorithm that converts an AST to a CST based on a grammar that only has binary rules can only spit out binary branching structures, so binarity of branching will take care of itself...

Comment: ... but doesn't that mean that the CST generated from an AST of the kind Tim has in mind would not correspond to any phrase structure grammar?

Comment: @rchivers It would correspond to a phrase structure (context-free) grammar, this is the result of Kaplan’s formal proof which he explicitly mentions. There’s no arbitrariness but their might be ambiguity, as I said above it’s a many-to-one relation so the algorithm is supposed to produce all CSTs arising from the input AST. The algorithm is one of the remarkable theorems in formal language theory that have profound consequences for linguistics (NL syntax).

Comment: @If a phrase has a functional head, then it has a head, which means it is not exocentric, but rather endocentric. Apparently you are drawing a distinction between function words and content words, whereby only content words can count as "true" heads. Your understanding of the distinction does not match what one finds in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocentric_and_exocentric

Comment: @TimOsborne You’re confusing categorial and functional heads. Mark Baker provides a very nice explanation of the dichotomy in his book on polysynthesis.

Comment: @Atamiri I do not think Bloomfield had that in mind when he first established the distinction. The classic exocentric structure for him was the prepositional phrase in English. He argued that neither prepsition nor noun could be deemed the head of the phrase.

Comment: @TimOsborne I’m using the “modern” definition of Hale, Baker and Bresnan (and the Wikipedia article you refer to). But thanks, I’ll read up on what Bloomfield wrote about it, for historical interest.

Comment: Surely the question is whether a CST showing elements that have no categorial head as dependent on a functional head corresponds to a dependency grammar (as that term is normally understood). I don't see how it can, if structures lacking categorial heads are incompatible with dependency grammar (as that term is normally understood). I can see that the CST is bound to show some kind of dependency relationship, but think that *dependency grammar* implies a particular kind.

Comment: @rchivers It’s actually very simple, every word has a functional head, except for the root of the tree. Categorial and functional heads are distinct concepts. If one accepts, say, the DP hypothesis, then the determiner is the categorial head and the noun the functional head, even in some weird theories that confuse the two notions. The incompatibility you mention is only apparent unless one completely ignores functional heads — but a theory that does ignore them is pretty much useless. You’re right that DG implies a “particular kind.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The same sources of recursivity in syntax, i.e. coordination and embedding, exist in both phrase structures and dependency structures. Both broad approaches can also be formalized in a way that is mathematically rigorous. For instance, one of the earliest articles on dependency grammar, i.e. [Hays 1964](https://www.jstor.org/stable/411934?seq=1), demonstrated that the rewrite rules (which allow for recursivity) associated with Chomsky's first works on syntax can easily be rendered in terms of dependencies. [Igor Mel'cuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Mel%27%C4%8Duk), the dependency grammarian behind the grammar framework known as [Meaning-Text Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning-text_theory), has always emphasized the importance of mathematical stringency when producing definitions of linguistic notions. In these respects, the answer to your question is "Yes".

In another respect, though, the answer may be "No". When it comes to analyses of sentence meaning in terms of formal semantics, there is a difficulty. Most approaches to formal semantics assume an understanding of meaning compositionality in terms of syntactic structures that are strictly binary in their branching. Dependency structures are incapable of mimicking this strict binarity of branching. What this means is that dependency syntax and much of the current work on formal semantics are incompatible to an extent. As a dependency grammarian, this issue has me viewing much of the work in formal semantics with skepticism.

Putting the emphasis on formalism aside, the great advantage that dependency syntax has over phrase structure syntax is its simplicity. I can teach novice linguistics students to produce dependency analyses of basic sentences in an hour or two. The same cannot be said of students learning to produce phrase structure analyses. Consider the next two tree structures in this regard:

[image]

The dependency tree has five nodes and four edges, whereas the phrase structure tree has nine nodes and eight edges. These numbers demonstrate the minimality of dependency structures compared to the corresponding phrase structures.

I think a comment concerning the value of formalization in linguistics is also appropriate. Heavy formalisms are difficult to penetrate for most people, and they are therefore often not helpful. In fact, over-formalization can be a means of masking the fact that the linguist behind the formalisms does not have much to say that is insightful, for if they actually had something insightful to share, they would express that insight in a manner that is accessible to a wide audience.

Comment: Why do you think that formal semantics requires binarity? They’re completely unrelated.

Comment: @Atamiri My exposure to formal semantics suggests that many such approaches, such as that by Caan (1993), assume a strict one-to-one matching of units of meaning to units of syntax. In order to maintain this approach, they need strict binarity of branching. Stefan Mueller has stated directly to me that strict binarity of branching is necessary in order to do semantics with syntactic structures. Think of currying; it is a good example of how function application is reliant on binary branching. I am all ears, though, if you want to convince me otherwise.

Comment: There might be approaches that require binary branching (such as CG together with λ-calculus) but that doesn’t mean that there aren’t other, less limited ways. One example is glue semantics, which uses linear logic (I’m not a big fan of glue semantics but it’s elegant and expressive). You might want to look at some papers by Mary Dalrymple.

Comment: If you had given a ps tree for "Trees can show syntactic structure" assuming the analysis of *Syntactic Structures* you might have drawn a different conclusion.  Was Chomsky not using phrase structure rules?  I think you have let a tree variety lead you astray about the forest you are in.  (Not everyone agrees with Ross that auxiliaries in English are main verbs -- for instance, I don't.)

Comment: @Greg Lee Your comment is overly brief and hence enigmatic. Which of my conclusions are you referring to? Yes, Chomsky's understanding of syntax is in terms of phrase structure (certainly not in terms of dependency structure). Concerning auxiliaries as main verbs, I certainly do not think they are main verbs, so what do you mean?

Comment: @TimOsborne You give a tree with both "can" and "show" dominated by "V".  Doesn't that mean they are verbs?  In the *Syntactic Structures* theory "can" is not a verb.  It's an Aux. The one and only verb in the sentence is "show", presumably the head, with "can" as one of its dependents.

Comment: @Greg Lee Yes, they are verbs. Please check in a dictionary of linguistics. My Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics says: "auxiliary (Aux). A verb belonging to a small class which syntactically accompanies other verbs...". You are nitpicking details rather than providing any commentary of substance.

Comment: @TimOsborne I don't need to consult a linguistic dictionary to find out what linguists say about this, since I actually am a linguist.  I look to evidence, not authority.  As usual, McCawley in his textbook *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* gives a very good summary of the controversy about Ross's theory that auxiliaries are verbs.

Comment: @Greg Lee What an inane comment! You are now seeming to claim that auxiliary verbs are not verbs. Why don't you produce a question for the forum that goes like this: Are auxiliaries verbs? I will then answer with linguistic arguments demonstrating that they are indeed definitely verbs.